# How can I prevent long equation from span two column page?

Tags: latex, equation

I have long equation with integral and summation process. how can I prevent it from span two column? I am tired using splitting and multiline but I have error missing } or ).

\begin{equation}

\hat{r}\left(t\right)=\frac{\sqrt{d}}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int{\left(y\left(t\right)+n\left(t\right)\right)P^\ast\left(t\right) \alpha _s\left(t\right)dt}\right)\ \gamma \left(t-mT\right)

\end{equation}

I want to break equation from % \alpha % to be in the second line. there is any idea to solve my problem?

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it belongs on [tex.se] instead of here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it already has a cross-network duplicate - [How can I prevent long equation from span two column page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/545350/5764) - with a posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

While you don't show us what you tried with `multiline`, `split` etc. the most probable cause of your problems is the unnecessary group after the integral sign. While this group does not hurt in a normal equation (but won't do anything good either) it will cause an error in `multiline` because you would split it over multiple lines.

In addition you need to make sure that the automatically resizing math delimiters are balanced within each line. This can be done by inserting `\right.` and `\left.`. Furthermore to force the delimiters in the second line to be the same size as in the first line one can use `\vphantom{\int}` ... or save all the trouble by manually choosing appropriate delimiter sizes.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}


\begin{multline}
\hat{r}\left(t\right)=\frac{\sqrt{d}}{\sqrt{2}}\sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int\left(y\left(t\right)+n\left(t\right)\right)P^\ast\left(t\right)\right.\\
\left.\vphantom{\int}\alpha_s\left(t\right)dt\right)\ 
\gamma \left(t-mT\right)
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but my equations is too long like this:

Comment: \begin{equation}

\hat{P}\left(t\right)=\frac{\sqrt{S}}{\sqrt{2}} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}{\left(\int_{\left(n-1\right)T}^{nT}\left(\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}{d\left(m\right)\varepsilon\left(t-mT\right)}\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\mathcal{a}_i+j\mathcal{b}_i\right)+\frac{n\left(t\right)}{\sqrt{S}}\right)\times\left(\left\{\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\mathcal{a}_i+j\mathcal{b}_i\right)\right\}^*\right)\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta\left(t-mT\right)\right)  \gamma\left(t-nT\right)}
\end{equation}

Comment: @hindalaskary If it is too long for two lines, you will have to split it over more lines (or change the layout)

Comment: yes sir, and unfortunately, I have many of them that prevent me  from make equation span into two columns.